# Return list using a loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, scheme, lisp, racket

I'm new to Racket. I'm trying to return a list of lists using a loop. The code works, but it only prints one of the elements 3 times without evaluating the other conditions, resulting in duplicates. How can I loop through each of the conditions and print one element for each condition without duplicates?

```
(define position_                                                                                                                             
  (lambda
      (list_) 
    (let ([size 3]) ;
      (for/list ([binary (in-range 0 size)])
        (cond [(not (empty? list_))
               (cond((list-ref list_ 0) (cond ((equal? (list-ref list_ 0) 1) (list (vector-ref Table 0) HIGH)) ((equal? (list-ref list_ 0) 0) (list (vector-ref Table 0) LOW))))                 
                    ((list-ref list_ 1) (cond ((equal? (list-ref list_ 1) 1) (list (vector-ref Table 1) HIGH)) ((equal? (list-ref list_ 1) 0) (list (vector-ref Table 1) LOW)))) 
                    ((list-ref list_ 2) (cond ((equal? (list-ref list_ 2) 1) (list (vector-ref Table 2) HIGH)) ((equal? (list-ref list_ 2) 0) (list (vector-ref Table 2) LOW))))  
               )])
        ))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `cond` has only **one term**. That means you have made something like this:

```
(cond [(not (empty? list_)) ...]
      [else 'pigs-are-flying]) ; what happens when the list is not empty
```

Now the result `pigs-are-flying` is only my suggestion. The truth is that the report specifically underspecifies it and that means everything goes.

Also know that `cond` is a if-elseif-else of Scheme so nesting `cond` is seldom required.. Eg. Code like this:

```
(cond [p1 c1]
      [else (cond [p2 c2]
                  [else a2])])
```

Is just a hard way to write:

```
(cond [p1 c1]
      [p2 c2]
      [else a2])
```

And if you want to do:

```
(cond [p1   
       (cond [p2 c2] 
             [else a2])]
      [else a1])
```

You can negate the predicate to get the same flat behaviour:

```
(cond [(not p1) a1]
      [p2 c2]
      [else a2])
```

As a style comment. Ending parentheses should never be on it's own line. It should be with it's friends on the previous line. It's the identation humans read, noe the parentheses. DrRacket does that for you so no need to adopt bad habits.

Comment: Yes i suspected nesting might be the case, ill adjust the code and see if it works

Comment: Also know that `p2` actually means `(and (not p1) p2)` since it only evaluates that if `p1` was false. Thus in a `cond` only one of the terms consequence expression will be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the logic as well as the syntax for the code to work, nevertheless it works perfectly now

```
(define position_                                                                                                                             
  (lambda
      (list_) 
    (let ([size  (length list_) ]) ;
      (for/list ([binary (in-range 0 size)])
        (cond [(not (empty? list_))
               (cond[ (equal? binary 0) (if (equal? (list-ref list_ binary) 1) (list (vector-ref Table 0) HIGH) (list (vector-ref Table 0) LOW) )]
                     [ (equal? binary 1) (if (equal? (list-ref list_ binary) 1) (list (vector-ref Table 1) HIGH) (list (vector-ref Table 1) LOW))]
                     [ (equal? binary 2) (if (equal? (list-ref list_ binary) 1) (list (vector-ref Table 2) HIGH) (list (vector-ref Table 2) LOW))]

                    )
               ]
               ))
        )))
```